# Identify parts of signal 1 in signal 2

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, vision

I have two audio signals, let's call them signal 1 and signal 2. Signal 1 is built of different parts of signal 2. For example, assume signal 1 is of length 15 seconds. The first 10 seconds of signal 1 came from 00:05-00:15 of signal 2. The remaining 5 seconds from signal 1 came from 00:30-00:35 from signal 2.

I try to find the timestamps of the "parts of interest" in signal 2, that is, the desired outcome would be `f(signal1,signal2)->{00:05-00:15, 00:30-00:35}`. I am wondering if there is a deterministic way to do the search, while not getting too complex. Signal 2 can be huge.

I am trying to find the joints in signal 1 by annotate the data and training a classifier. Then, given that this classifier will be adequate and finding those joints, it then becomes a search problem I can solve in [O(n log n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75965921/find-the-most-similar-subsequence-in-another-sequence-when-they-both-numeric-and). Is there a simpler (and hopefully cheaper way) to do that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution

Comment: Cross correlation (which is basically the same as convolution) will also give you peaks at the times that signals are most alike (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation).