# Matching parts from cut sequence to origin sequence, when origin sequence is very long

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have two numeric and huge np.arrays (let's call them `S1` and `S2`, such that `len(S1)>>len(S2)>>N` where `N` is a very large number). Let us call `S1` the origin sequence, and `S2` the cut sequence. `S2` is built of different subsequences from `S1`. Although it is usually that subsequences are chronological in `S2`, that is, if one part comes after another in `S2`, it was like that in the original file as well, we have some cases when they reversed. Lastly, there are also some cases, when there is a noise, so the match can't be exact. Here are two examples of possible `S1` and `S2`s:

```
S1 = [1,12,5,2,4,6,124,5,23,65,75,12,56243,21,54]         # Original sequence
S2a = [1,12,5,      124,5,      75,12,56243]               # Chronological order
S2b = [1,12,5,                  75,12,56243,   124,5]      # Reversed order
S2c = [0.995,12,5.01,      124.1,5.5,      75.2,12,56242]  # Chronological order with noise
```

**I would like to find the locations of the subsequences from the origin (`S1`), that appear in the cut (`S2`). They both are quite long, to the searching got to be efficient.**

```
# Desired output
12a = [0:2, 6:7, 10:12] # Chronological order
12b = [0:2, 10:12, 6:7] # Reversed order
12c = [0:2, 6:7, 10:12] # Chronological order with noise
```

It is a follow up question of my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75965921/find-the-most-similar-subsequence-in-another-sequence-when-they-both-numeric-and), with a new complication, unfortunately. Also here, I guess that the results would involve some cross-correlation, but the trick here is, that `S2` is now comprised of a mix of subsequences.

Sometimes a split can be inferred by looking at its properties, like whether it is continuous or not. I tried to build a classifier to detect splits in the sequence, and to follow the suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75965921/find-the-most-similar-subsequence-in-another-sequence-when-they-both-numeric-and). However getting examples is costly, and I an looking for something more feasible.

Comment: I'm assuming there aren't overlapping sequences. What is the minimal length of subsequence? What are the lenghts of the arrays?

Comment: Assumption correct, minimal I would say in the tens to a few hundreds, total lengths can be huge, in the hundred thousands.

Comment: What is the allowed number of elements in slices?

Comment: severals, let's assume less than a 100